# android application download file

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

My current Android application downloads a number of audio files. When I employ this code to execute the download I get file not found exception:

```
try {

    final URL downloadFileUrl = new URL("http://filelocation/url.m4a");
    final HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) downloadFileUrl.openConnection();
    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
    httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
    httpURLConnection.connect();

    mTrackDownloadFile = new File(Record.this.getCacheDir(), "mediafile");
    mTrackDownloadFile.createNewFile();
    final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mTrackDownloadFile);
    final byte buffer[] = new byte[16 * 1024];

    final InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

    int len1 = 0;
    while ((len1 = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len1);
    }
    fileOutputStream.flush();
    fileOutputStream.close();

} catch (final Exception exception) {
    Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground - exception" + exception.getMessage());
    exception.printStackTrace();
    mTrackDownloadFile = null;
}
```

When i employ this code it works fine:

```
try {

    final URL downloadFileUrl = new URL("http://filelocation/url.m4a");
    final URLConnection urlConnection = downloadFileUrl.openConnection();

    mTrackDownloadFile = new File(PlayOpponent.this.getCacheDir(), "mediafile");
    mTrackDownloadFile.createNewFile();
    final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mTrackDownloadFile);
    final byte buffer[] = new byte[16 * 1024];

    final InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    int len1 = 0;
    while ((len1 = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len1);
    }
    fileOutputStream.flush();
    fileOutputStream.close();
} catch (final Exception exception) {
    Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground - exception" + exception.getMessage());
    exception.printStackTrace();
    mTrackDownloadFile = null;
}
```

Can someone please point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [blog](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/195330) removing

```
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
```

in your code may solve the problem. It's said to be a ICS issue.

Comment: nice one, i will give that a try and get back to you

Comment: This blog post describes the problem: http://webdiary.com/2011/12/14/ics-get-post/